# Correct type for sqlite connection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

Still new to Python typing, what would be the correct type to replace the ??? here?

```
def update_sqlite(result: dict, db_connection: ???):
    pass

with sqlite3.connect('../data/Reports.db') as report_db:
    update_sqlite(result, report_db)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, you're talking about [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)? The correct type is [`sqlite3.Connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection).

Comment: Seems too easy. ;)

Comment: And e.g. for the cursor it would be sqlite3.Cursor